# AWS ALB/Cloudfront file upload - returns status code 413

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, kubernetes-ingress

### Context

I am running my applications using CloudFront, S3, ALB, and Kubernetes. The backend(which is the API) is running in Kubernetes(EKS), exposed using a public ALB. The frontend runs as a static site hosted in S3 bucket and served via cloudfront. All this is managed via Terraform.

### Problem

When I upload a file greater than 7MB, the upload fails. If I check the API logs in the k8s container, I see:

```
 Completed 413 Payload Too Large in 1651ms
```

As you can see status code of 413 is returned.

My ALB snippet is:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "example" {
  metadata {
    name      = "example_name"
    namespace = "example_namespace"

    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"                = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme"           = "internet-facing"
  ...
    }
...
```

Any idea why I'm getting this?

Comment: 413 too large is when the target is a Lambda function... Is the target configured correctly?

Comment: @hephalump the target isn't a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

This limitation can be related with current settings of your **nginx ingress controller**. As you can read in its [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size):

> **Custom max body size**
>
> For NGINX, an 413 error will be returned to the client when the size
>   in a request exceeds the maximum allowed size of the client request
>   body. This size can be configured by the parameter
>   `client_max_body_size`.
>
> To configure this setting globally for all Ingress rules, the
>   `proxy-body-size` value may be set in the [NGINX ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-body-size). To use custom
>   values in an Ingress rule define these annotation:
>
> ```
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
> ```

So if you don't want to set this option globally in **nginx ingress controller** `ConfigMap`, you can adjust it by adding the following annotation to your **ingress resource definition**:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Asker didn't use `nginx`, `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` was set to `alb`, not `nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the request included body payload more than 6mb that alb not supported and 413 error thrown. I still also faced to this issue, same infras except we have serverless host by AWS lambda. The simple solution which I tried is using the front-end to upload the file to AWS s3 and generate presigned URL to download if needed